# SQL Select - Date Comparing In Complex Query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I want to get all the rows whose dates are the closest to current time.
To do that, I am first getting the first closest date to current from all the rows, then getting all the rows whose date is the same as this closest one.
Hope that makes sense..

This is it:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Events 
 WHERE StartDate = '(SELECT StartDate 
                       FROM Events 
                      WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE() 
                      ORDER 
                         BY StartDate DESC 
                      LIMIT 1)';
```

Any way, the query does not work. I know the sub query does work:

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE StartDate = SELECT StartDate FROM Events WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE() ORDER BY StartDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

But when combining them together, it won't run.
I suspected it might be a matter of format of the sub query's result, I tried using the sql functions to format it but that did not work either.

I do not have access to the debugging errors as well so I can't really see what's wrong.

Can you try help out?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: are you sure the date is a date ONLY, and not date + time? As posted below, lose the quote and leave the parenthesis. It's an event, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't order by `DESC` to find the closest. You need ascending order:

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE StartDate = (
    SELECT StartDate FROM Events WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE()
    ORDER BY StartDate LIMIT 1
)
```

Or you could:

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE StartDate = (
    SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM Events WHERE StartDate >= CURDATE()
)
```

Comment: I took it from the internet and did not examine it thoroughly.
You, sir, are a complete badass! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query is a string. Remove the quotes.

Comment: From what I'm familiar with, dates use quotes.
Anyway I tried both and that still doesn't do it.

Comment: You removed the quotes _and_ the parentheses.